# Is array name a pointer in C language?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know that a pointer in C language is a variable that holds an address.
for example:

```
int myVar;
int *p;
p = &myVar;
printf("%p\n", p);
printf("%p\n", &p);
```

The output will be two different addresses, the first one is the address of myVar and the second one is the address of the pointer itself which means a pointer is a variable also and have an address in memory (Correct me if I'm wrong)

But my question is about arrays, for example we have this code:

```
int myArray[10];
```

so here I thought myArray is a pointer also that holding the address of the starting point of myArray which in this case is myArray[0], so when I print address of myArray[0] and myArray I get same result:

```
printf("%p\n", &myArray[0]);
printf("%p\n", myArray);
```

Now the confusing part for me is here when I try to print the address of myArray itself:

```
printf("%p\n", &myArray);
```

Here I get the same results I was expecting to get another address like pointers.Is myArray a 
label or something?

Comment: why did you expect to get another address?

Comment: https://www.studytonight.com/c/pointers-with-array.php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&myArray[0]` is the address of the first element of the array, `&myArray` is the address of the array. These must have the same address, but are different types.

`myArray` is *not* a pointer. It is an array that *decays* to pointer of type `int*` under certain instances. Being a parameter of `printf` is such an instance.

Comment: Good answer! OP: try adding the following, if you want to get even more confused: `printf("%p\n", *(&myArray));` and `printf("%p\n", *(&myArray[0]));` for maximum effect, initialise your array: `int myArray[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };`